# Android Studio error: Consider deleting _JAVA_OPTIONS

Tags: android, android-studio, kali-linux, javaoptions

I am working on Kali Linux and wanted to get started with Android development and Flutter but I am getting this error after installing Android Studio:

> The use of Java options environment variables detected. Such variables override IDE configuration files (*.vmoptions) and may cause performance and stability issues. Please consider deleting these variables: _JAVA_OPTIONS.

What does this mean and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning comes up because you have an environment variable called `_JAVA_OPTIONS` setup by default. On Kali Linux, this variable typically carries default formatting/encoding for your Java installation.

- To view the value of this variable, use `printenv _JAVA_OPTIONS`.
- To delete the value of this variable, use `unset _JAVA_OPTIONS`.

Once removed from your environment variables, Android Studio will no longer display the previous warning.

[Edit]: I noticed that after deleting the variable, Android Studio was now able to build projects that were previously failing to build.

NB: If you foresee a need for the variable elsewhere, you can copy it out and move it into your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` (comment it with `#`) for later use.

Answer (score 3):

**For windows**

1. Search for  **env**.
2. It will bring two options

   **.Edit environmental variables for your account**

   **.Edit the system environment variable.**
3. Choose option two to edit the system environments.
4. It will open a pop-up of **System properties**. where you will go to the Advanced settings tab.
5. Bellow the tab you will find **Environmental variables**.It will also open another tab with

   **.User variables**

   **.System Variables**
6. Go to the system variable. There you will find your  **_JAVA_OPTIONS** path.
7. Delete it and refresh your android studio. The error should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I am using **Kali Linux** at the moment. The following command `printenv _JAVA_OPTIONS` works, but only temporarily. If you are interested in knowing why? Visit [site link](https://superuser.com/questions/1529159/why-i-cant-permanently-remove-these-environment-variables-into-an-ubuntu-18-04). Once you restart android studio the error pops up again.

Here's my workaround:

- Open your bash terminal.
- Unset the variable; `printenv _JAVA_OPTIONS`
- Switch your current directory to that of your android studio launcher, usually in; `android-studio/bin`
- Then launch your android studio; `./studio`

Here's an elaborate example:

[image]

In my case, the error didn't pop up. The process seems tedious for every android studio launch but at least it works. I hope my answer helps the next victim.

The following script should make work easier. Just remember to make it executable by;

- `chmod +x <file_name.py>`
- **The script:**

```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python3

  """Script to counteract _JAVA_OPTIONS error in android studio"""

  import subprocess
  import os


  def studio_launcher():
      """android-studio launcher"""

      # change dir to android-studio dir
      os.chdir('/opt/android-studio/bin')
      # execute launch
      subprocess.Popen(['./studio.sh'])

  me_status_code = os.system("printenv _JAVA_OPTIONS")

  #If printenv is successful
  if me_status_code == 0:
      print("We in")
      try:
          print("Try to unset")
          del os.environ["_JAVA_OPTIONS"]
          print("Unset successful")
          studio_launcher()
      except SystemError:
          print("Sth went wrong!!!")
          studio_launcher()
  else:
      print("Var empty!!")
      print(me_status_code)
      studio_launcher()
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to @antony-kavoo. You can avoid re-doing the process by running the below command:

```bash
echo 'unset _JAVA_OPTIONS' >> $HOME/.zshrc
```

*Note: if you are using bash, use `$HOME/.bashrc`*